# Coordinator work with RecyclerView 'A' and RecyclerView 'B' in RecyclerView 'A'

Tags: android, material-design

coordinatorlayout work with recyclerview 'A' and another recyclerview 'B' in  recyclerview 'A'.
recyclerview 'B' as a item in recyclerview 'A'

[image]
[image]

See above images.

If scroll UI start from 'Part A' . It's ok. Toolbar hide or show.

If scroll UI start from 'Part RecyclerView'. Toolbar's stuck.

Why???

Edit01 :

> ```
>   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>       android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
>
>       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>           android:background="#fefefe"
>           android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
>           app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
>           app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
>           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">
>           <!-- custom layout -->
>       </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
>
>   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
>       android:id="@+id/viewpager"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="match_parent"
>       android:scrollbars="none"
>       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
> ```

ViewPager contains Fragment , and the Fragment contains RecyclerView. Let's show you the item of RecyclerView

> ```
>   <RelativeLayout
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
> ```

```
            // Part A
```

> ```
>       <RelativeLayout
>           android:id="@+id/rl_artist_info"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>           android:padding="@dimen/item_card_artist_margin">
>        </RelativeLayout>
>
>        //Part RecyclerView
>        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>            android:id="@+id/rv_artist_product"
>            android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="@dimen/item_card_artist_products_height"
>            android:layout_below="@id/rl_artist_info"
>            android:scrollbars="none"/>
>    </RelativeLayout>
> ```

```
If scroll UI start from 'Part A' . It's ok. Toolbar hide or show.
If scroll UI start from 'Part RecyclerView'. Toolbar's stuck.
```

Comment: Can you post your xml layout? make sure you have the layoutBehaviour on all the needed views.

Comment: You are saying U have Nested RecyclerView inside the Coordinatorlayout . If Yes Can you paste your xml and LayoutManager for both RecyclerView

Comment: @Vipinhelloindia I use default LayoutManager. I pasted xml in `EDIT` .

Comment: @Nanoc  I pasted xml in `EDIT`.